# Update Contact Object Using Guest Site User

Tags: force.com-sites, profile

As Salesforce suggested
These guest user site profiles are associated to guest user licenses which give the ability to **only read/create** on standard objects and **not update**.

Is there any workaround to update Contact standard object from Salesforce Site?

Comment: I think I have got this functionality and I know it shouldn't be possible....the main vulnerability (I guess) is allowing randoms to update other people contacts, in my form the contact fields are displayed but I lookup the email to see if a record exists. On save I issue an upsert.  The site permissions show read/create and the field level permissions show as visible and that's all I've done I think.... If I look at a record via salesforce the feed shows " crm test site guest user changed last name from... To..." So it does seem to work???? Wondering how as the answers are all true...

Answer (score 5):

A solution to this problem is to create a custom object with fields that map to fields on the standard object to be updated and give permission to the guest user to update this new object type. Include a reference to the standard object from this 'shadow' object to form a link between the custom and standard records. Create an insert/update trigger on both the custom and standard objects to keep the 2 in-sync so that when the custom is updated it updates the standard record to match.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in different ways but the most simple is using the keyword "**Without Sharing**" in the controller for that page.

```
public without sharing class yourcontroller {

     //update logic here
}
```

[More info](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Without_Sharing)

Comment: pretty sure that doesn't work - the guest site user doesn't have update access regardless of permissions granted via sharing

Comment: We do this to allow the guest user to update their account and it definitely works.

Comment: Is this guest user logging in though? I don't believe an anonymous guest user sessions on sites can update a standard object?

Comment: No, the user is not logging in. I actually just verified this works right now.

Comment: Yeah - that just worked for me too...I stand corrected. I swear that didn't used to work though - I have always ended up using the approach suggested by Richard Durrant...

Answer (score 0):

You could try implementing via an @future method. From the guest site you'd pass your intended field values and contact record id to the @future method, where you would then instantiate a new contact sObject using the id you passed it, and then perform an update.

Comment: pretty sure that doesn't work - the @future still runs in the context of the guest site user

Comment: Maybe. Sure Ive done something like this before. Will test.